# Summing values from cells based on value on other cell on the row (Excel)

Tags: excel

Can you help me with adjusting this VBA Excel module function:

```
Public Function SumByCellValue() As Double
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim xRg As Range, yRg As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each xRg In .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
            If UCase(xRg.Text) = "TRUE" Then
                If yRg Is Nothing Then
                    Set yRg = .Range("C" & xRg.Row)
                Else
                    Set yRg = Union(yRg, .Range("C" & xRg.Row))
                End If
            End If
        Next xRg
    End With
    If Not yRg Is Nothing Then SumByCellValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(yRg)
End Function
```

I try to select values from column C based on values on column A. Value I want to match is "TRUE", so all rows that has "TRUE" in column A should be summed up and returned by function.

VBA debugger does not give any error, but when using function in worksheet, it says #value!.

Comment: Why not use `SUMIF`? And why `As Range`?

Comment: Why not use SUMIF():  `=SUMIF(A:A,TRUE,C:C)` or `=SUMIF(A:A,"TRUE",C:C)` depending on whether the value in a is the boolean `TRUE` or a text string.  BTW if it is the Boolean TRUE then remove the `="TRUE"` from the if in your code. and just test the cell, `If xRg.Value Then`

Comment: Compared value is a string. Ill try suggested sumif function. Didnt know about it.

Comment: Also I first had it to return range. Now changed to sum inside function to double.